# "cold cash" vs. "hard cash"

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences, money

Context ([New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/05/business/markets.html?_r=3&pagewanted=2&hp)):

> Besides piling into Treasuries, institutional investors are also
>   seeking out the safety of **cold**, **hard cash**, pouring billions
>   into commercial bank accounts backed up by the Federal Deposit
>   Insurance Corporation.

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cold+cash):

> **cold cash**: Also, **hard cash** .  Actual currency (bills and
>   coins); money immediately available, paid at the time of a purchase.

The Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary lists *cold cash*
 as American English, and *hard cash* as British English.

Is the OALD correct? Is there a difference between these two terms or not?

Comment: Note that "cold, hard cash" usually appears as an expression with both words together in American English (I've never heard "cold cash" on its own, as far as I can remember).

Comment: @aediaλ - I've heard "cold cash" a fair amount, but "hard cash" -- not so much.

Comment: My takings from that bank I robbed last week may be "hard cash", but it's not "cold".  (Though, OTOH, I guess it isn't reasonable to call a wad of bills "hard cash" either.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As aedia pointed out, in American English you are more likely to hear "cold, hard cash" than "cold cash" alone. In light of this, here are two Google Ngrams comparing *cold cash*, *hard cash* and *cold, hard cash*.

In American English:

[image]

In British English:

[image]

I realize that "hard cash" will include the counts of "hard cash" on its own, and "cold, hard cash". However, in both cases *hard cash* is far more likely. Using just "cold cash" and "hard cash" in the NGram discounts the use of both together. Therefore, it seems as if *hard cash* is more likely in both dialects of English.

Answer (score 1):

A comparison on Google's **Books Ngram viewer** - [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cold+cash%2Chard+cash&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) vs [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cold+cash%2Chard+cash&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) - shows that **cold cash** is almost non-existing in British English but used quite extensively in American English.

So with the assumption that you can conclude anything from this, OALD is correct.